# awk taking file names instead of files in for loop

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, csv

Okay so I need to extract a certain column with awk from a certain file, put it in an array and then sort it, and afterwards I would need to look up some values within these extracted sorted columns with awk too, but for now I have some problems with my for loop:

```
for var in $1 $2
do
myarr=($(awk -v row=$3 -F';' '$row!="" {print $row}' $var))
sorted_array=( $( printf "%s\n" "${myarr[@]}" | sort -n ) )
echo "${sorted_array[@]} $var"
done
```

The output is:

```
 dbdump.csv
 dbdump2.csv
```

which are the names of the two csv files I want to extract the column from
. If anyone could provide some kind of solution it would be much appreciated because i need this script to search stuff. Also if you can suggest an algorithmically faster approach please do, this was just me learning some bash scripting and trying to put together some code.

Input files contain records like this, and I have two of those files that don't have matching values in column 3(that's what my manager said):

```
1101590479;Frank Haemers;;20060310;1;RESI;;01;06;0007;0000000000;;CRM000;
1101590473;Van KetsmJan;;20060310;2;PROF;;01;08;;0000000000;75;CRM000;0686143950
```

The two files have around 5 million of those records. I have another file with a certain amount of patterns that must be looked up those two huge csv files, and if one of those patterns matches in either of files I need to output into another file something like:

```
echo "$pattern has been found in $file"
```

I need to do this for all the patterns found in my patterns text file

Comment: This is what is known as an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You seem to be trying to use a language that is great for text processing (`awk`) only as a tool to extract data and do the actual processing in a language that is absolutely *crap* for text processing (shell). I suggest you [edit] your question, show us an example of your input files and your final desired output and ask for help on doing the actual processing rather than this, almost certainly unnecessary, preprocessing step.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Need a bit more though. We also need an example of the patterns you are looking for. You mentioned sorting, is this also a requirement? What about the 3rd column? Are you only interested in matches on the third column? Should we assume columns are defined by `;`? By the way, are you just looking for `grep -FLf patterns.txt file1.csv file2.csv`?

Comment: sorting is not required, and columns are defined by a ; and I am interested to match a column that I provide in the positional parameters and I am looking to be able to provide more than two files if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a shell script, it is best to specify the verified variables first, and filenames last, so you can vary the number of files specified. In your case, you have the column number, a file with the patterns in it, and two (or perhaps more) file names to work on. So, start your Bash script with

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -lt 2 ] || [ "$1" = "-h" ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ]; then
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: $0 [ -h | --help ]"
    echo "       $0 COLUMN PATTERNFILE [ FILE(s) ... ]"
    echo ""
    exit 0
fi
```

The `if` clause above uses old-style POSIX shell formatting, and will work in `dash` (and other POSIX shells) as well as in most old-style `sh` shells as well. The intent is that if the user does not specify any command line arguments, or just a `-h` or `--help`, the script just prints a short help text.

You should expand on the help text, by the way, because it makes it much easier to find out what it does in two or three months, after you've forgotten you wrote it. (Happens to me all the time, and I have *lots* of such scriptlets, so I've found this practice well worth the little effort.)

Next, extract the required parameters (only one, above), and `shift` them out, so that we can use `"$@"` to refer to all file names specified on the command line:

```
column=$1
patternfile="$2"
shift 2
```

Note that I like to put double quotes around stuff I want expanded in the shell, even when not explicitly necessary. This is because most real-life problems I encounter with shell scripts are due to *forgetting* quoting an expansion, when it would have been necessary. This practice is easy to remember, and other than having some know-it-all comment that "you don't actually need those double-quotes there" in an annoying nasal tone, they do no harm.

Lets then use `awk` to process the input files:

```
awk -v column=$column \
  'BEGIN {
       RS = "[\t\v\f ]*(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n|)[\t\v\f ]*"
       FS = "[\t\v\f ]*;[\t\v\f ]*"
   }
```

The backslash at the end of the first line above just tells the shell that the command continues on the next line. Also note that there is no closing single quote `'` , so the lines below are actually continuation to the command-line string parameter we are supplying to `awk`.

The `BEGIN` rule in awk is executed before the files are processed. The above `RS` sets the record separator to any newline convention, and includes any leading or trailing whitespace on each line. Similarly the field separator is a semicolon, but including any whitespace surrounding it. Thus, `a ; b` has two fields, the first being `a` and second `b`, neither having any whitespace.

I use the following idiom to keep track of which input file is being processed:

```
    FNR==1 { ++filenum }
```

If just means that for the very first record in each input file we process, we increment the `filenum` variable. Incrementing an uninitialized variable is the same as incrementing a zero, so we get `1` for the first input file, and so on.

We want to just remember the contents of each line in the first input file, our pattern file:

```
    filenum==1 { pattern[$0] }
```

Awk arrays are associative, so we can just use an associative array to hold the known patterns. Above, we use a funny awk feature to our advantage: If you try to access an associative array entry that does not exist yet, awk creates it!

For the rest of the files, we just check if the field `$column` (supplied to the awk scriptlet in awk variable `column`) matches (exactly) any of the patterns seen in the first file, and if so, we print the entire record:

```
    filenum > 1 && ($column in pattern) { printf "%s\n", $0 }
```

Above, `$column` has a different meaning compared to a shell script. Here, `column` is a variable, and `$column` expands to the value of the `column`'th field in the current record (zeroth column being the entire record, however). The `foo in array` syntax is awkism for checking if `array` contains a key `foo`. So, overall, for the second and further input files, if the `column`'th field value was listed in the first input file, the record is printed. to standard output.

We are still in the `awk` command-line parameter string, and need to close the single-quoted string. We also want to supply it with the file names:

```
    ' "$patternfile" "$@"
```

which concludes this awk scriptlet.

Comment: This would be much easier to understand if you also included the final script and not only its parts. I *think* you're making this more complex than necessary but can't really tell without seeing the entire script. For one thing, though, you can use `FILENAME` instead of fiddling with an incrementing counter.

Comment: Wow thanks, so yeah I have been fiddling with awkward stuff for this entire morning trying to resolve this, but you provided a comprehensive explanation on how would you do it and for that I thank you. Do you have any guidelines on what should I pick up first in text processing because I fathom I might have a lot of these coming. Thanks again!

Comment: @CristianBaciu first rule: never, *ever* attempt to do text processing in the shell. It's just not built for it, it is very slow and will make everything harder. look into tools like `sed`, `awk` and `perl` instead.

Comment: @terdon: You do need to copy and paste the code together to see the final script. It was a deliberate choice, intended to ensure that anybody *really* interested in writing a shell-and-awk scriptlets also reads the accompanying text, rather than just take the code and use it without understanding how it works, and why it was constructed the way it is. I personally dislike the `FILENAME==ARGV[n]` idiom (being true if the current input file is the `n`th input file specified), but sure, that'd be a viable alternative to the argument numbering.

Comment: @CristianBaciu: Start with having a problem you want to solve, similar to the issue at hand. Then, take the time to browse through the GNU [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) and [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) manuals (introduction, notes, examples -- no need to start reading from front to back), and start working. There's probably a lot of good tutorials on them on the web, too; maybe pick one or two that suit your needs and current skill level?

Comment: @terdon: I know that having the scriptlet split into pieces makes it frustrating to see if the scriptlet is garbage or not, to point out enhancements or even fixes, but personally, I'm willing to forego that if it means my example code will not be used as someones homework answer. (Not by OP in this instance; the task is just very generic, so by later solution-finders.) I do welcome others' counterexamples, though!

Comment: @NominalAnimal no, I mean `print FILENAME` to get the name of the file, no need for `FNR==1 { ++filenum }`. See my answer for an implementation of what I mean.

Comment: @terdon: Ah, now I see! I don't actually print the input file name at all, only the records with a matching field themselves; our output differs. You use `NR==FNR` as a rule which matches on the first file, whereas I use `FNR==1 {++filenum}` and then `filenum==1` for the same purpose.  However, I am actually assuming that there will be future rules that need to act differently on specific input files. My entire scriptlet is intended more as a scaffolding to build on, rather than a minimal solution to the stated problem, you see. (It's also why I have such a wall of text.)

Comment: Fair enough. On a completely different note (mod hat on), I saw that you haven't upvoted the question despite spending so long writing an answer for it and checked your profile. You've only cast *a single vote* in the 9 months you've been here! Eeeek! Please vote, and please vote often. If our established users don't vote, the site becomes as useless as a forum. If anything, up/down voting is even more important than providing answers.

Comment: @tendon: Absolutely not. I have my own small rebellion against the unbelievably silly belief that *popular answers* have anything to do with technically correct, verifiable answers. I refuse to play such a useless eusocial game. See my comments in [this meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338376/user-refusing-to-correct-misinformation-in-their-popular-answer) for context. I shall wage my small rebellion for as long as I am tolerated here; but rather than submit to silliness, I will simply stop participating here, as I have had to elsewhere before, for very similar reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to take a list of patterns and a set of files and print out the names of all files that matched each pattern in a specific column, all you need is GNU `awk` (default on Linux):

```
awk -F';' '{
                if(NR==FNR){ 
                    p[$0]++; 
                    next
                } 
                if($3 in p){
                    printf "%s found in %s\n", $3,FILENAME; 
                    nextfile
                }
            }' patterns file1.csv file2.csv fileN.csv
```

#### Explanation

- `awk -F';'` : set the field separator to `;`.
- `if(NR==FNR){ p[$0]++;next}` : `NR` is the current input line number and `FNR` is the current file's line number. The two are equal only while the first file is being processed. This will therefore save each line of the patterns file (the 1st file) in the array `p` and go to the `next` line. It will only be run for the patterns file.
- `if($3 in p){printf "%s found in %s\n", $3,FILENAME; nextfile`: Now we're looking at the csv files. if the 3rd field is one of the elements in the array `p` (if it was in the patterns file), print the 3rd field (the pattern) and the filename it was found in. Then, skip to the next file. The `FILENAME` variable holds the path of the file currentloy being processed. The `nextfile` is a gawk feature and does what it says on the tin: it skips to the next file to be processed.

For example, given these files:

```
$ cat patterns 
foo
bar
baz

$ cat file1.csv 
blah;blah;foo;blah
blah;blah;foo;blah
blah;blah;foo;blah

$ cat file2.csv 
blah;blah;bar;blah

$ cat file3.csv 
blah;blah;baz;blah
```

You will get this output:

```
$ awk -F';' '{if(NR==FNR){p[$0]++; next} if($3 in p){printf "%s found in %s\n", $3,FILENAME; nextfile}}' patterns file*csv 
foo found in file1.csv
bar found in file2.csv
baz found in file3.csv
```

If you can have each pattern present in multiple files, you can use a slightly different approach:

```
awk -F';' '{
            if(NR==FNR){ 
                p[$0]++; 
                next
            } 
            if($3 in p && !seen[FILENAME][$3]){
                printf "%s found in %s\n", $3,FILENAME; 
                seen[FILENAME][$3]++
            }
        }' patterns file1.csv file2.csv fileN.csv
```

This time, there's no `nextfile` since we need to process the entire file and there's a counter that is incremented each time a pattern has been found in a given file so we don't report the same pattern multiple times.

So, changing the `file1.csv` above to:

```
$ cat file1.csv 
blah;blah;foo;blah
blah;blah;baz;blah
blah;blah;bar;blah
blah;blah;foo;blah
```

We get:

```
$ awk -F';' '{if(NR==FNR){p[$0]++; next} if($3 in p && !seen[FILENAME][$3]){printf "%s found in %s\n", $3,FILENAME; seen[FILENAME][$3]++}}' patterns file*csv 
foo found in file1.csv
baz found in file1.csv
bar found in file1.csv
bar found in file2.csv
baz found in file3.csv
```

If this is too slow, as it might be for huge files, you can modify it so that it stops reading a file if all patterns have already been found in it:

```
awk -F';' '{
            if(NR==FNR){ 
                p[$0]++; 
                next
            } 
            if($3 in p && !seen[FILENAME][$3]){
                printf "%s found in %s\n", $3,FILENAME; 
                seen[FILENAME][$3]++
            }
            if( length(seen[FILENAME]) == length(p) ){
                nextfile
            }
           }' patterns file1.csv file2.csv fileN.csv
```

Comment: Thank you both you just solved a lot of my future problems :D